# Large Number of Routes Found

Tags: community, digital-experience

I have the following "tip" appearing when in my Community.  I need help understanding what it is telling me & what to do about it.

Large Number of Routes Found
This site is using 328 routes. We recommend keeping the number of routes below 250.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted a page & the # in the tip dropped to 327.  Apparently, the word routes in the tip refers to Community pages.

Comment: A "route" is a distinct URL, typically a page. Your observation is correct. Too many routes will cause performance problems. Depending on what you need, it's probably a better idea to have one page that can serve dynamic content depending on parameters.